# Markdown insert external image with get variables

Tags: image, variables, get, markdown

I need to embed an external image in a web page using markdown syntax, but the image's url is not a *real* image file (eg. jpg/png): it's an api with some get variables in it and the following example I've tried does not work.

```
![image description](https://domain.tld/myImage?varA=valueA&varB=valueB "image text")
```

If I put that url within the src attribute of an <img> tag it works.

Any clue?

Comment: This works just fine, e.g. using https://placeholder.com/ or http://placekitten.com/ with GitHub READMEs. Which renderer are you targeting? And can you provide more information about the specific image service you're using?

Comment: @Chris the markdown is parsed by openuserjs.org and the image service is provided by buymeacoffee.com
Thanks in advance.